# TextBox with the same clipping as TextBlock (TextBox Template)

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, controltemplate

The `TextBlock` element treats `LineHeight` nicely, allowing the text to display fully, without clipping. However, I want to change it to a `TextBox` to facilitate editing the text and this is where my trouble starts.

The `TextBlock` display the text like this:

[image: Tall letters display beyond the hight of the TextBlock]

The `TextBox` display the text like this:

[image: Tall letters are being clipped!]

I've tried to fiddle with the `ClipToBounds` and `Clip` properties, but it only clips within the element and will not expand beyond the borders.

The `LineHeight` property needs to be set low to regulate the gap between the lines so it's not an option to change.

I've also tried `Padding`, but it only does this

[image: Padding, but text is still clipped]

I'd go out of my way and listen on key presses and change the text accordingly if that's the only solution, but it seems like a lot of work and I don't think it'd be a good solution, so here's my condensed question:

How do I make `TextBox` not clip text the same way as `TextBlock` if it is at all possible?

---

**Update** Here's the styling code (what I currently have anyway) and where it's applied.

```
private static Style GetFontTextBlock()
{
    var style = new Style();
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.LineStackingStrategyProperty, LineStackingStrategy.BlockLineHeight));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.IsHyphenationEnabledProperty, true));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BorderBrushProperty, null));
    return style;
}

public static Style GetHeadline()
{
    // ApplyFont sets the Control.FontFamilyProperty to Geogrotesque Condensed Regular.
    // It's a purchased font so I can't supply it, unfortunately
    var style = ApplyFont(new Style { BasedOn = GetFontTextBlock() });
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, 140));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.LineHeightProperty, 112));
    return style;
}
```

It's applied to this control within a `UserControl`

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Background="Cornsilk" Name="Headline" AcceptsReturn="True" />
    ...
    </StackPanel>
    ...
</Grid>
```

---

**Update**
Based on Cadogis answer, the style setter code turned out to be as follows:

```
public static Style GetHeadline(Enums.Enums.SheetSizes size, object triggerTarget)
    [...]
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.TemplateProperty, XamlReader.Parse(
        // Breaks and indentation for readability
        @"<ControlTemplate TargetType='TextBox'
            xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>
            <DockPanel>
                <Decorator Name='PART_ContentHost' />
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>")));
    return style;
}
```

Which produces the much desired result

[image: TextBox with TextBlock clipping!]

Thanks to both of you for helping me!

Comment: Have you tried setting `ClipToBounds` to `True`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. I've updated the question.

Comment: In case anyone see this and know a plausible solution; this is still a problem to this day.

Comment: What layout do you use that produces this? Any styles involved? Could you give some code?

Comment: @tabina Here's the code. I hope answers your questions.

Comment: Are you using different styles for the TextBox-variant? The styles you're defining contain properties that are not available for TextBoxes.

Comment: I'm aware that some of them, like `LineHeight` and `LineSpacingStrategy` aren't applicaple to `TextBox` directly, but they still have an effect on the displaying part of the box, which I believe to be a `TextBlock`. I've also added a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something here but when calling your textbox , you can set min and max values for height and width then just set them to auto e.g.

```
<TextBox Text="Test&#xA;test" Style="{StaticResource HeadlineFontTextBoxStyle}" 
AcceptsReturn="True" Height="Auto" MinHeight="24" MaxHeight="120" />
```

I should point out that using this in a stack panel will restrict the height be default, using a grid will give you the best results, as it will expand on the fly.

Obviously you don't want the control to expand indefinitely, so the max properties will reign it in if its getting too big, but "Auto" should allow it to size properly. Sorry if I've completely missed the point.

---

***Template idea***

Not sure if this is quite what you would be looking for but it's a modified template for a textbox to to render outside the border (it uses a decorator instead of a scrollviewer) - figured i should try to give an option that might work.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FontTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy" Value="BlockLineHeight"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.IsHyphenationEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="HeadlineFontTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.LineHeight" Value="100"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy" Value="BlockLineHeight"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="140"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <DockPanel>                           
                        <Decorator Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="Test&#xA;test" Style="{StaticResource HeadlineFontTextBoxStyle}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
</Grid>
```

For reference you might want to look at this from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Resizing is fine when I enter more lines, there's a lot of available vertical space and it all works good, except the line height is so small that the glyphs become taller than what the text box can display. In a `TextBlock` element the "excess" is rendered, whereas `TextBox` clips it. I need to be in this strange scenario because of requirements to the small line spacing. This is the core of the problem and I cannot find a way to circumvent.. Oh if only I could set the `LineHeight` property per line or magically set `PerformIrationalClipping` to false.

Comment: Ok, I was missing the core issue. The real problem is that you are explicitly setting the font size to be 18px bigger than the line height as the default unit is px when no qualifier is used - [link TextBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize(v=vs.110).aspx) - also the same with LineHeight - [link TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.lineheight(v=vs.110).aspx) .So you have two options 1) reduce the font size 2) create a custom control to overlap the lines of text or custom template a TextBox.

Comment: *sniffls* I was afraid that that'd be the answer.. I really hope that there's a better/easier way than your second suggestion cause the first one isn't an option, unfortunately. Perhaps there isn't. In that case you'll win the bounty.

Comment: hope the template points you in the right direction, but I think it basically does what you are looking for (rendering outside its bounds), you just need to tweak some properties for how you want it to work/look.

Comment: Actually I found this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/421aee0d-c0d1-4d24-90d1-23fd9a8e915d/how-do-i-add-hyphenation-to-a-wpf-textbox?forum=wpf before you updated your answer, but yours does exactly what I want and in a much neater way too! Thank you so much Cadogi, bounty well earned.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your settings (rewritten in styles in xaml) and with the TextBlock, I see the same display as you. But with the TextBox, the letters are fully visible, nothing is clipped.

```
 <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FontTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy" Value="BlockLineHeight"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="TextBlock.IsHyphenationEnabled" Value="True">  </Setter>
      <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="HeadlineFontTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource FontTextBoxStyle}">
      <Setter Property="TextBlock.LineHeight" Value="122"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="140"></Setter>
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="Testtest" Style="{StaticResource HeadlineFontTextBoxStyle}" />
  </StackPanel> 
 </UserControl>
```

Comment: To get the same endresult as I have, use a `LineHeight` of 100 or 110. This will produce the same effect with the different font.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo. Sorry.